# TFS Automated Build System issue

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, tfs, msbuild, build-automation

I am preparing a course for TFS 2015, and I've got almost everything, except the Automated Build part, which is giving me some problems. I'm currently having a huge issue when trying to build an example project. That project has one html file and a few JS ones, just for testing things out.

Then, I prepared an agent on-premises that connects to my Visual Studio Online account, which is properly bound to that TFS instance. My build definition is simple: the default one, with the directory set to my project's directory ($testing).

Everything should run fine, but I'm having the following error. It was with some parts in spanish, but I translated them for your understanding:

> 2015-10-07T18:27:23.2436618Z Executing the powershell script:
>   C:\agent\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.15\VSBuild.ps1
>
> ```
> 2015-10-07T18:27:25.0057796Z ##[error] Cannot find property DirectoryName.
>
> 2015-10-07T18:27:25.0227790Z C:\agent\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe restore "C:\agent\_work\3\s" -NonInteractive
>
> 2015-10-07T18:27:25.2377919Z ##[error]Cannot locate a solution file.
>
> 2015-10-07T18:27:25.2617935Z ##[error]Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe
>
> 2015-10-07T18:27:25.2727677Z C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe "C:\agent\_work\3\s" /nologo /m
> ```
>
> /nr:false /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\agent_work\3\s.log"
>   /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\agent\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"*ForwardingLogger,"C:\agent\agent\worker\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"
>   /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="debug"
>   /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0"
>
> ```
> 2015-10-07T18:27:25.4188021Z MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project's file doesn't exist.
>
> 2015-10-07T18:27:25.4188021Z Modificador: C:\agent\_work\3\s
>
> 2015-10-07T18:27:25.4228024Z ##[error]Unexpected exit code received from msbuild.exe: 1
> ```

What's going on with my build definition? I should have this ready soon, but I don't find any info about these errors... Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

*You're actually working with TFS nNext build (adjust from the VSBuild.ps1).*

And I can reproduce your above error when I specify the **Solution** field in the **Visual Studio Build** step with a folder which has no solution or project to build. So, to resolve it, explicitly specify one .sln or .csproj file. Like:

[image]